# Convert dB A to dB SPL

Tags: power, audio, measurement, sound

I am trying to calibrate an audiometer that gives outputs in dB SPL. However, the sound meter that I am using to calibrate the audiometer registers in dB A. Is there a formula to convert from dB A to dB SPL?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is SPL, just weighted to match the [Fletcher-Munson curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fletcher%E2%80%93Munson_curves).  A weighting most closely matches the log nature of human hearing. Converting isn't exactly trivial. There are various rules of thumb around the internet, but the linearity of both of your devices will come into play. If you need any precision, the best option is to buy/borrow/steal a measurement microphone, a certified calibrator, and appropriate software, and use that as your baseline. The software will allow you to select different weightings, and see the difference between them in the frequency domain.

Comment: The tools you mentioned seem very helpful, but I would like to do the calculations myself to understand the theory or logic behind converting from dB A to dB SPL. Therefore, I am wondering if a formula for conversion exists.

Comment: Think about it. There couldn't possibly be a formula to convert between the two. The whole system's frequency response has to be factored into the final reading.

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole system's frequency response has to be factored into the final reading"?

Comment: Your meter has a microphone, and amplifier. The microphone will most likely not have a perfectly flat frequency response.  The amplifier will most likely be pretty flat. Then it's going to get converted to digital and go through some signal processing. The non-linearity in the system will be known to the designers, and they will account for it when they calculate the SPL in code. Further, you can't just convert between A, C, flat, or whatever SPL weighting. If you look at the Fletcher-Munson curves, they are frequency and SPL dependent.

Comment: This stuff isn't trivial and people that do it, do it for a living.

Comment: I see -- thanks! A follow-up: It seems that I do not understand dB A and dB SPL as well as I need to. Do you have a brief explanation of how they are related, or do you know a good resource that explains the relationship between them? I have been looking for a while but haven't found a clear explanation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-weighting

Comment: @ Matt Young -- Good resource.  I was talking with some other people in my psycholinguistics lab, and we are wondering if it would be possible for us (without getting a degree in electrical engineering or something similar and specializing in instrument calibration) to learn how to calibrate the audiometer or learn to do what a professional does.  We are certainly willing to work and would be interested in training.  We have training in acoustics and related areas; we just don't have calibration training.  We primarily want to know if it is physically impossible or if it is simply hard.